# Run program as .exe dll miss match? (Method not found)

Tags: c#, dll, windows-runtime

I need to get the names from the smartcard on my computer from inside a service.

I have this program to write the names of all smartcards to a file.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.SmartCards;

namespace DeviceEnumerationConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnumerateDevices().Wait();
        }

        static async Task EnumerateDevices()
        {          
            try
            {
                string selector = SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector();              
                DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
                string ret = "start1 ";
                foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
                {
                    ret = ret + device.Name + " _ ";
                }

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ProgramData\IDNORTH\cards.txt", ret);

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ProgramData\IDNORTH\error.txt", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This work great when I run it on it's own.

However when I run it from outside it sometimes work and sometimes returns

Method not found: `Void System.Threading.Tasks.Task.AddToActiveTasks(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)`.

from line:

```
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```

I believe from the error there is some problem with the dlls.
In project I have added the references.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winm‌​d

and

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\Tools\MDILXAPCompile\Framework\Sys‌​tem.Runtime.WindowsR‌​untime.dll

I call the exe from a service and have not added or changed any references in that. It has the same windows reference as the one added to Project1.

Comment: I am not sure this is going to help you. Since you said it is not working but sometimes. This clearly indicates some kind of 'timing' issue. 1. When you are not specifying the thread type,by default it is 'Foreground' thread, so even if you don't 'wait' on it, the thread that created still waits till the 'foreground thread' completes. 2. Now, there is a time limit for windows service 'OnStart', it should complete its work within 15 secs and should give the control back to OS, otherwise it will be considered as failure and windows will abort the process.

Comment: My guess is that your DoWork is taking more time, and due to the time limit for the OnStart event the process is terminated.

Comment: Are you synchronizing the work done in project1.exe? Would it be the same issue if you wait for the `Process.Start` to complete before starting a new one?

Comment: Are you getting an exception in Project1.exe or in the service?

Comment: The error is always on DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector); in the project.exe

Also I believe it is about the same number of errors for every success regardless of how long I wait between the calls on the exe. So if I have no delay at all in the service and just spam the project.exe as fast as possible I get a correct file instantly. (as well as the error file). I also believe it is determined extremelly fast if it works or not = the card/error.txt are created instantly, certainly no 15 sec delay when it does not work.

Comment: Did some test now where I called the exe 200 times from the service with different delays and added the int from the for loop to the file name to see how many succeded and how many got errors.
When I had 30 ms delay I got 10 cards.txt created and the rest errors, when I changed it to 300ms I got 8 cards.txt. So seems not to matter. If it throws the error or created the card.txt seems to be determined immediately when starting the exe and not be depending on any other requests. Like some random event. Very peculiar.

Comment: Is it the same project1.exe file that is called? MissingMethod usually means that some dll is not up to date. Are you some how exchanging dlls in your project directory?

Comment: Are you targeting multiple .net frameworks?

Comment: May be you should wait for execution of Process1.exe before calling it again

Comment: Sounds like you are on to something! When I created the project.exe I basically just added references more or less randomly until I got Windows.Devices to work.. There is probably some miss match somehow which causes problems.

In Project1 I have
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd
and
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\Tools\MDILXAPCompile\Framework\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
In the service I seem to ave the same windows, is it the windows runtime in project that is wrong then probalby?

Comment: OK changed the reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll and now it seems to work everytime.
Thank you Default for getting me on the right path.
Would mark you as answer but don\t think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the procedure but thought I should mark this as answered since it works now.
Changed the reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.‌​WindowsRuntime.dll

Thanks to Default!